# Problem in Mac OS terminal while running code Visual Studio

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio-mac

I have this problem, when press "run" button in visual studio on Mac OS.

For example, I write `Console.WriteLine("Hello World");` and press `Run`. Then it opens the console and I see this message in the console.

```
bash -c 'clear; 
cd "/Users/kirill/Documents/.
```

I have to say, that all projects I create are saved in `Users/kirill/Documents/C#`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I have edited your question, please check if the code block is correct.  And could you explain what is the problem in the terminal?

Comment: When you want to provide more details, edit the question. The comments are for asking for clarification.

Comment: looks like the shell is interpreting the `#` in your path (in not bash savy enough to say how). Try changing the directory to something... less special. Also file a bug with Microsoft since they should be escaping such things to avoid problems and attacks both.